# Best practices for common logic on classes

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a big big class, around 4000 thousands lines, and I think it can be another way to do the following.

It is a class for serialize a message, the nested classes are always with the same structure and overrides the ToString and Equal methods. There are simple classes like the following and complex classes which implements those simples classes in properties.

My idea is something like an extension class who implements the override and extend the simples classes with it

Example class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class ID
{
    #region Public Properties

    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public String Value { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public static bool operator == (ID left, ID right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator != (ID left, ID right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override bool Equals (object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((ID) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode ()
    {
        return (Value != null
                    ? Value.GetHashCode()
                    : 0);
    }

    public override String ToString ()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected bool Equals (ID other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Value, other.Value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My idea

```
public class FieldExtension
{
    public String Value { get; set; }

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public static bool operator == (FieldExtension left, FieldExtension right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator != (FieldExtension left, FieldExtension right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override bool Equals (object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((ID) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode ()
    {
        return (Value != null
                    ? Value.GetHashCode()
                    : 0);
    }

    public override String ToString ()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected bool Equals (ID other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Value, other.Value);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class ID: FieldExtension
{
    #region Public Properties

    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public String Value { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I don't know if this is possible and I just ask if some did that before or something like that or another ideas, if works will save me a lot of work

Thanks in advance

EDIT
Example complex class

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Zählpunkt
    {
        #region Public Properties
        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public ID ID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Zählpunkt")]
        public String Value { get; set; }
        #endregion
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would make the base class `FieldExtension` abstract, and the `Value` property abstract:

```
public abstract class FieldExtension
{
    public abstract String Value { get; set; }
    ...
```

Then in the `ID` class you override the property:

```
override public String Value { get; set; }
```

That makes the code in the base class use the value that you implement in the class that inherits it.

Comment: Ok, get it, I know that had to be a way, I edit my question to see if this solution would work also for the complex classes, maybe you can take a look on it.

Comment: @TareqB.: If you want to use the base class to implement the functions for the complex class, you would need to override the `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString` methods to do something sensible with all the properties. That would however mean that it also got a `Value` property, so you might want to do a different base class for those.